# touch friendly dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a touch friendly drop down menu, but don't know how to.
Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="mainMenu">
    <nav role='navigation'>
    <ul class="active">
        <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="http://#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a href="http://#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-109"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14"><a href="http://#">Dropdown process</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-110"><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-111"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-114"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a href="http://#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>  
</div>
```

Demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/cb8ev58m/

It is a wordpress menu.
How do I make sure that when user click on Dropdown link, they are not redirected to that page, but dropdown is opened. If they click on that link again, then they would be redirected.

Comment: I presume you want to do this with Javascript/jQuery? If so I would use javascript to change the class of the open menu and use event.preventDefault() to only target the closed menu class.

Comment: I am not very good with javascript. I want to prevent link to open if it has chidlerns. So in this case I want to prevent Dropdown link to open on first click. 
I did read about touchstart, but not sure how it works exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First click - open, second - redirect. 
But what about the hide submenu ?

```js
var clicked = {};
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(e){
  var $li = $(this).closest('li');
  $li.siblings().each(function(){
     $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp();
     $(this).find('.menu-item-has-children').each(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
         if( id in clicked) delete clicked[id];
     })
 });
  if( !($li.attr('data-id') in clicked)){
     e.preventDefault();
     clicked[$li.attr('data-id')] = true;
  }
  $li.find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
})
```

```css
.mainMenu {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul {
        position:absolute;
        top: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        left:0px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        font-size: 20pt;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul li {
        color:white;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
        transition: all ease 0.5s;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul li:hover,
    .mainMenu nav ul li:focus {    
        background-color: #FFCA00;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .mainMenu nav ul li a {
        color:white;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
        transition: all ease 0.5s;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul ul{
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background:transparent;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul ul li {
        border-radius: 0px;
        float: none; 
        position: relative;
        min-width: 135px;
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul ul li a {
         
    }
    .mainMenu nav ul ul ul {
        position: relative; 
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainMenu">
                    <nav role='navigation'>
                      <ul>
                        <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="http://#">SubMenu</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a href="http://#">SubMenu</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-109"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14"><a href="http://#">Dropdown process</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-110"><a href="#">SubMenu</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-111"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
  <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-114"><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a href="http://#">Menu</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <a class="toggle-nav" href="#"> </a>
                    </nav>  
                  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I need. Is there any way to show only one dropdown menu opened? If dropdown01 is opened and I open dropdown02 then dropdown01 should close. Is that possible?

Comment: Toggle dropdown would also be a nice feature.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTML `<button>` instead of an `<a>` and use CSS to hide the `<ul>`:

```
ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

button:focus + ul.sub-menu, ul.sub-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Afterwards you can fix the button behavior via JS. (Optimize for mobile, open link on click if it has focus etc.)

Edit:

You could also hide the `<button>` if it has focus and add the "Dropdown" Link as `<a>` to the `<ul>` below. This does not need JS for a basic version.

```
button:focus {
    display: none;
}
```